# Is a continuous surjective map with finite fibres also closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous and surjective  map between topological spaces. Moreover assume that $f$ has finite fibres (i.e. finitely many points). Is it true that $f$ is closed?

Notice that here I am not assuming that $f$ is covering space, or that the fibres have the same cardinality.

Comment: Let $f$ be the identity from $ X= \Bbb R$ in the discrete topology to $Y=\Bbb R$ in the usual topology. Fibres have size $1$ and continity is trivial, but $\Bbb Q$ is closed in $X$ while $f[\Bbb Q]=\Bbb Q$ is not closed in $Y$, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

No, $f$ need not be closed. Any continuous bijection $f:X\to Y$ that is not a homeomorphism is a counterexample. More conditions must be added to conclude that $f$ is closed.

However, you might be interested in the notion of a [proper map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) (preimages of compact sets are compact). Whenever your map $f$ with finite fibers is closed, it will be a proper map. In other words, under your current hypotheses, closed implies proper. Hence, to conclude that $f$ is closed you will at least need to add enough assumptions to ensure that $f$ is proper. Maybe you're content with assuming $f$ is proper if you really want $f$ to be closed.

For example, if you assume that $f$ is proper and that $Y$ is compactly generated (a $k$-space) and Hausdorff, then you can conclude that $f$ is closed.